# Identify image request in servlet by filename in URI instead of as request parameter

Tags: image, servlets

I use a servlet to get images that saved out of my project. Code in my servlet is:

```
String file = request.getParameter("file"); 
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(directory + file));
// Get image contents.
byte[] bytes = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(bytes);
in.close();
// Write image contents to response.
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

The HTML image tags are like this:

```
<img src="/images/?file=example.jpg" />
```

Everything is good. But now I would like to have image filename in URI instead of as request parameter like so:

```
<img src="/images/example.jpg" />
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the servlet on a prefix URL pattern `/images/*` instead of an apparently exact URL pattern  `/images`. Then, you can specify URLs exactly like that and obtain the filename as URI path information by [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

Kickoff example:

```
@WebServlet("/images/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        File file = new File(directory, filename);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: [`InputStream#available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) as in your initial code doesn't do what you apparently thought it does. It doesn't return the entire length of the content. It just returns the length of the first block which the code can read without blocking the disk file system I/O. I.e. it returns the length of content currently in I/O buffer. This does not necessarily represent the entire content length! For sure not on larger images. If you're on Java 7, just use [`Files#copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) if the sole purpose is to achieve the job with least possible amount of code as shown above.

Comment: Finally found the answer :)